# Set MIME type after PHP interpreting

Tags: php, apache, mime-types, httpd.conf

When I use

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml .pwml .php5 .php4 .php3 .php2 .php .inc .htm .html
```

in httpd.conf, the files with the given extensions start being interpreted by PHP interpreter. But all of them also start having 'text/html' MIME type.

I know I can use

```
<?php header("Content-type: WHATEVER"); ?>
```

in the files themselves, but is it possible to assign a MIME type right after PHP interpreting for an extension, using the same httpd.conf?

What I want is a way to make any file type being interpreted by PHP, no matter what extension, and don't write header manually, since it always can be inferred from extension. In other words, I want to keep the MIME type a file would have if there wasn't assignment to PHP interpreter.

Comment: so do you want to make a rule for all extensions to be set automaticly?

Comment: try to edit `/etc/mime.types` this file countains all extension and their headers

Comment: @K3rnel31 It looks like the line from mime.types is overridden to text/html if you assign the extension to application/x-httpd-php. At least, I explicitly set the custom MIME type in this very file and the file is still text/html.

Comment: @noober the browser can not identify the type of application/x-httpd-php it converts it to text/html

Comment: @K3rnel31 Oh, I see now. I used to think the type is changed to text/html on server side. OK, then how to make PHP interpreter to process the files, but not setting its type to application/x-httpd-php?

Comment: @Artur I don't understand about mod rewrite. Could you please add some info?

Comment: mmm as i see you want that you request application/x-httpd-php on your server-side and process it on php ?

Comment: @K3rnel31 I want, for instance, .txt remains text/plain (as it is in `mime.types`) without <?php header("Content-type: text/plain"); ?>, but the same time being processed by PHP.

Comment: this is by defaults on your `mime.types` file open it and you will see `text/plain     txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default ie. when:
your ***mime.types*** does not contain (*):

```
application/x-httpd-php php
```

line and your ***httpd.conf*** does not contain (**):

```
PHPIniDir "C:/PHP/"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/PHP/php5apache2_4.dll"
```

(or similar depending on php's path and apache version)

.. any request to ***php*** file will return php's source code (not interpreted) and Apache will not set **Content-Type** so it is up to your browser how to interpret it (google Mime-type sniffing). Usually you'll just see your source code in the browser's viewport.

If your ***mime.types*** contains (*) and ***httpd.conf*** does not contain (**) it will tell Apache to serve your ***php*** files with **Content-Type: application/x-httpd-php**. Hovewer it will still be a source code and your browser will ask you whether to open/save requested resource.

In general if your ***httpd.conf*** contains (and loads php module this way):

```
PHPIniDir "C:/PHP/"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/PHP/php5apache2_4.dll"
```

(or similar depending on php's path and apache version) ... ***mime.types*** line:

```
application/x-httpd-php php
```

serves slightly different purpose than expected. It no longer provides MIME type for **Content-Type: ...** HTTP response. It tells Apache which file extensions should be sent to PHP interpreter. You can put to your ***mime.types*** the following line:

```
application/x-httpd-php xyz
```

and it will tell Apache to send contents of any file with ***xyz*** extension to PHP interpreter but your HTTP response will have **Content-Type: text/html** set and not as you might think **application/x-httpd-php**.

So you can accomplish what you want by adding this to your ***mime.types***:

```
application/x-httpd-php phtml pwml php5 php4 php3 php2 php inc htm html
```

Of course you must have your PHP module loaded.

You may also want to read about [mod_rewrite apache module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Still even if you interpret files with ***xyz** (whatever) extension as PHP you may freely change content type using:

```
header('Content-Type: ....');
```

Comment: @K3rnel31: Do you think that if some part of my answer is within comments I do not know what I am talking about here? It takes some time to write it as it is longer than comments.

Comment: That's very interesting, but how get rid of header('Content-Type: ....');? This is the question. Even if there is no lines of <?php ?> in a file, I should add this line! Then I cannot just copy income files! I have to process them manually, adding header at the top! This is what my question is about.

Comment: @noober: You do not have to get rid of it - it is not necessary. What I meant in last sentence is that by changing content type from php you may force browsers to interpret what you output as an image (whatever - even pdf): header('Content-Type: image/png'); echo file_get_contents(png_file);